# How to always display VIM buffers in a status below instead of using ls?

Tags: vim

When I use VIM and buffers, to see the list of all the buffers, I always have to type `:ls` to see all the buffers.

Is there a way to have the buffers always be displayed at the bottom of vim?

Edit:
So basically let's say I have 2 files open in vimand if I type in :ls it will display something like

```
  1 #h   "IModuleTest.php" line 422
  3 %a   "~/.vimrc"        line 1
```

Instead of typing that to see all my files open, I want to see them all the time so I can switch between them faster instead of seeing the buffer list first..

Comment: Sure but I still have to toggle through all the buffers to find the one I want (Let's say I got 10 of them). VS seeing the number of the one I want right off the bat and doing :b<buffer number>

Comment: See `:help wildmenu`. Also `nnoremap gb :ls<cr>:b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that do that; for example, [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159).

Actually, this need sounds strange. Do you know that commands like `:buffer` also take a filename, and auto-complete it, too?! GVIM has a *Buffers* menu by default. And many users have plugins like CtrlP, FuzzyFinder, or Unite to quickly locate buffers and files.

Comment: How isn't that like what the minibufexpl.vim plugin provides?!

Comment: Well I was trying to see if that was possible without plug ins.. but just installed it and it's working but the buffers are displayed at the top. Is there a way to move it to display at the bottom?

Answer (score 4):

I like this plugin ["vim-bufferline"](https://github.com/bling/vim-bufferline)

First good thing is that it shows up on the empty, unused space of command line, once it finds that the command line is inactive/idle for ~3seconds. And it disappears once we press : (start of a command).

Then it shows on command-line a list of all the buffers open in the Vim and also highlights the active buffer on which the cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

Lua function to list buffer names **within statusline**  with active one hightlighted:

```
vim.cmd('hi ActiveBuffer term=underline cterm=underline ctermfg=none ctermbg=none')   

function set_status(args)
       local buffs = {}
       local no_list_buffs = {['']=true, ['[Command Line]']=true}
       for _,v in pairs(vim.fn.getbufinfo({buflisted=1})) do
                local fname = vim.fn.fnamemodify(v.name, ":t")
                if(not no_list_buffs[fname]) then 
                    if(v.bufnr == args.buf) then
                        fname = '%#ActiveBuffer#'..fname..'%*'
                    end
                    table.insert(buffs, fname)
                end
        end
        vim.o.statusline = '%F%m %y%='..'<'..table.concat(buffs, ',')..'>'..' %c,%l/%L %P'
    end
```

To invoke use autocmd:

```
 vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'BufEnter'},
 { 
            group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('BufStatusLine', {}), 
            callback = set_status 
 })
```